# Using Stat(2) to compare to files if the same dont copy

Tags: c

I'm learning C currently,. Using Stat(2) system call How would I compare 2 files st_ino(Inodes) & st_dev(device) and if the same, not to copy the file from source to destination.

I can't find any good examples online

I am looking at this code http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~lib215/lectures/lect02/5_Code/llcopy.c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have the idea how to do it, just try to translate your thoughts into code:

```
struct stat src, dst;
int err;
err = stat(src_file, &src);
if (err < 0) {
    perror("stat");
    exit(1);
}
err = stat(dst_file, &dst);
if (err < 0) {
    perror("stat");
    exit(1);
}
if ((src.st_dev == dst.st_dev) && (src.st_ino == dst.st_ino)) {
    // same file, skip copy
}
// copy the file
```

check out http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: Thanks for the website! :)

Comment: Hey I dont know what im doing wrong but i've put the if(src. etc and I've did printf statement saying the file is the same, exit then else I put the copy statement. It seems to work If I copy the same file src to the same file dsc it gives me the printf statement but it also tries to copy it? Is exit not enough?

Comment: @josh `exit` will cause the program to terminate. It must be something else.

Comment: Oh Woops I found my error I have the wrong statement in the else Should have been the O_CREAT statement :)!